# Users with highest sum up price

Tags: mysql, query

I have a table with name, email, user_id, and price. On this table, a user can appear more than once depending on how many purchases. I am trying to get select all details of users with the highest sum of price.

```
id   name  price   email    user_id
--   ----  ----- ---------  -------
1    Mike  100   @mike.com      5
2    John  50    @john.com      6
3    Mike  100   @mike.com      5
4    John  50    @john.com      1
5    Mark  50    @mark.com      3 
6    Mike  100   @mike.com      5
```

As you can see from above Mike has the highest pricing in total I want a query that will get the sum total of column "price" and select all details of the row with the highest total first in an array and follow by the next higher. The result should be like below:

```
id   name  price   email    user_id
--   ----  ----- ---------  -------
1    Mike  300   @mike.com      5
2    John  100   @john.com      6
3    Mark  50    @mark.com      3
```

I want the 'id' to reset and start listing 1,2,3,4,5... and also I have other columns on the table I will like to get.

Also in addition I will like to know the count(how many times the users purchase).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you want this.

The problem is that john has 2 user_ids 1 and 6
Else i would put the user_id also in the GROUP BY

AND if you only the highest 3 You have to add also LIMIT 3
A **MySQL 5.x** Solution to your problem

> ```
> CREATE TABLE sumprice (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `name` VARCHAR(4),
>   `price` INTEGER,
>   `email` VARCHAR(9),
>   `user_id` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO sumprice
>   (`id`, `name`, `price`, `email`, `user_id`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', 'Mike', '100', '@mike.com', '5'),
>   ('2', 'John', '50', '@john.com', '6'),
>   ('3', 'Mike', '100', '@mike.com', '5'),
>   ('4', 'John', '50', '@john.com', '1'),
>   ('5', 'Mark', '50', '@mark.com', '3'),
>   ('6', 'Mike', '100', '@mike.com', '5');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT   @id:= @id +1  `id`, `name`, SUM(`price`) price , `email`, MAX(`user_id`)
> FROM sumprice,(SELECT @id:=0) a
> GROUP BY `email`, `name`
> ORDER BY price DESC
> ```
>
> ```
> id | name | price | email     | MAX(`user_id`)
> -: | :--- | ----: | :-------- | -------------:
>  1 | Mike |   300 | @mike.com |              5
>  2 | John |   100 | @john.com |              6
>  3 | Mark |    50 | @mark.com |              3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=a1be35034eb87833380820540640b7b4)*

In **Mysql 8**

> ```
> CREATE TABLE sumprice (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `name` VARCHAR(4),
>   `price` INTEGER,
>   `email` VARCHAR(9),
>   `user_id` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO sumprice
>   (`id`, `name`, `price`, `email`, `user_id`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', 'Mike', '100', '@mike.com', '5'),
>   ('2', 'John', '50', '@john.com', '6'),
>   ('3', 'Mike', '100', '@mike.com', '5'),
>   ('4', 'John', '50', '@john.com', '1'),
>   ('5', 'Mark', '50', '@mark.com', '3'),
>   ('6', 'Mike', '100', '@mike.com', '5');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
>         ORDER BY SUM(price) DESC
>     )  `id`, `name`, SUM(`price`) price , `email`, MAX(`user_id`)
> FROM sumprice
> GROUP BY `email`, `name`
> ORDER BY price DESC
> ```
>
> ```
> id | name | price | email     | MAX(`user_id`)
> -: | :--- | ----: | :-------- | -------------:
>  1 | Mike |   300 | @mike.com |              5
>  2 | John |   100 | @john.com |              6
>  3 | Mark |    50 | @mark.com |              3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c6d4a92aa8744ddafa8204cdf67d91ac)*

In **Oracle** it is the same

> ```
> CREATE TABLE sumprice (
>   id NUMBER(5),
>   name VARCHAR(4),
>   price NUMBER(5),
>   email VARCHAR(9),
>   user_id NUMBER(5)
> );
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO sumprice
>   (id, name, price, email, user_id)
> VALUES
>   ('1', 'Mike', '100', '@mike.com', '5');
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO sumprice
>   (id, name, price, email, user_id)
> VALUES('2', 'John', '50', '@john.com', '6');
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO sumprice
>   (id, name, price, email, user_id)
> VALUES  ('3', 'Mike', '100', '@mike.com', '5');
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO sumprice
>   (id, name, price, email, user_id)
> VALUES  ('4', 'John', '50', '@john.com', '1');
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO sumprice
>   (id, name, price, email, user_id)
> VALUES  ('5', 'Mark', '50', '@mark.com', '3');
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO sumprice
>   (id, name, price, email, user_id)
> VALUES  ('6', 'Mike', '100', '@mike.com', '5');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
>         ORDER BY SUM(price) DESC
>     ) id ,name, SUM(price) price , email, MAX(user_id)
> FROM sumprice
> GROUP BY email, name
> ORDER BY price DESC
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | NAME | PRICE | EMAIL     | MAX(USER_ID)
> -: | :--- | ----: | :-------- | -----------:
>  1 | Mike |   300 | @mike.com |            5
>  2 | John |   100 | @john.com |            6
>  3 | Mark |    50 | @mark.com |            3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0d7a2c534818b26987a81aa3019d7e53)*

Comment: i assume you use mysql 8 and oracle have a row_number function

Comment: Both works for my database. Also in addition I will like to know the count(That is how many times the users purchase).

Comment: Your new updated code throws an error: Static analysis:

17 errors were found during analysis.

An alias was previously found. (near "`id`" at position 70)
Unexpected token. (near "`id`" at position 70)
Unexpected token. (near "," at position 74)
Unexpected token. (near "`name`" at position 76)
Unexpected token. (near "," at position 82)
Unrecognized keyword. (near "SUM" at position 84)
Unexpected token. (near "(" at position 87)

Comment: @yodeveloper so not Oracle then?

Comment: The "Static analysis" phrasing [suggests MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43666624/230471) (I'd never seen it before either), so the Oracle tag seems to have been a mistake.

Comment: it seems to be a phpmyadmin error message, but this also would not throw 17 errors.

Comment: it is an error i got from the query I did on my database server.

Comment: show us a fiddle that throws that error, because i can't find 1 errors even in phgpmyadmin, but i use mysql 8

Comment: I want able to resolve this error my upgrading my database version from VERSION() 5.7.31 to 8 and the query works fine now.

Comment: I added also a mysql 5 version of the code

Comment: @nbk hope the upgrade of my version won't affect anything?

Comment: no every thing works as before, nut wth the new function, there are a lot more possibilities winowd function as ROW_NUMBER LAG and so on increase the possibilities to wirte need code, also when you want to use json the increased teh number of functions

Comment: @nbk thanks so much